# Contents of address bar in WebBrowserClass

Tags: .net, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to get the contents of the address bar or search bar in Internet Explorer using the WebBrowserClass (from a band object)?  I can get the contents of the address bar *if* the user has navigated, but if I want to just get what was entered I can't seem to do it. Is this possible?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, right?

Comment: Not working with the Windows Forms WebBrowser class.  This is using COM interop as part of a BandObject (toolbar plugin) in IE.  I want to access the IE address bar.  Since IE itself is a shell around the web browser object, any access to its own properties would be some other interface.  I just don't know what.